# AWS Lambda Test S3 Event Notification is Null

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have the following Kotlin code:

```
 override fun execute(input: APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent): APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent {
        val response = APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
        val body = input.body
        if(body != null) {
            val json = JSONObject(body)
            val s3 = json.optJSONArray("Records").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("s3")
            val bucketName = s3.getJSONObject("bucket").getString("name")
            try {
                val jsonResponse = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mapOf("message" to bucketName))
                response.statusCode = 200
                response.body = jsonResponse
            } catch (e: JsonProcessingException) {
                response.statusCode = 500
            }
        }

        return response
   }
```

I want to basically get the function to be triggered on a new S3 put and just get the bucket name. When I try locally to pass a `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent` with the following body:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "example-bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "test%2Fkey",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The kotlin code works as expected. When I deploy this on AWS lambda, and I either provide the exact same body in a test event or actually uploading an object on S3 to trigger the function, the `input.body` is null. I don't understand why.

Comment: Typically `body` represents an HTTP body e.g. in an HTTP POST request. S3 event notifications don't look like that. Log the event and see what it contains.

Comment: Are you using API Gateway somehow?  I'd expect a Lambda responding to a S3 event to try to handle `S3Event`, not `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent`